# Using react component (Map) as background image?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a react component which generates a static map. I would like to use that map as the background of a Bootstrap card which contains some text.

I have tried using overlay, z-index and other CSS tools, but no matter what I try, the Map seems to completely cover all of the card's content. Is it possible to use react components in this way?

See below for the snippet of relevant code. I do know that 'card-img' Bootstrap class would not work for the LeafletMap component because its not an image, this is just to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

JSX:

```
<div className="card rounded my-3 shadow-lg current-card">
    <div className="card-top text-center">
        <div className="day-date my-3">
            <p>Saturday, March 15th</p>
            <span>...</span>
        </div>
    <LeafletMap className="card-img-top" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.day-date{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. It's hard to tell what the problem is with so little code, but let me guess: did you set `position: relative` on the `<LeafletMap>` component? For it to work properly, the `<LeafletMap>` component cannot be `position: static`, which is often the default, or [z-index has no effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Thanks mate, good to know for future. checked this and may have been part of the problem but main issue was a class generated by the library that had a z-index of 400! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem, Leaflet library generates a class on its maps called 'leaflet-container' that has a z-index of 400. I overrided that with a !important and the problem was solved.